# What is the condition to split integral in Lebesgue theory?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,1]^2\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$f(x,y)=1/y^2 \text{ if }0\leq x <y<1$$
$$f(x,y)=-1/x^2\text{ if }0\leq y <x \leq 1$$
$$f(x,y)=0 \text{ otherwise}$$
If can show that $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy \neq \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dydx$$
In my course, it is written that the last equation does not contradict fubini's theorem since $\mid f\mid$ is not integrable on $[0,1]^2$. I don't know why and I can't compute the integral of $\mid f \mid$ on $[0,1]^2$. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Tonelli's Theorem $\int |f| \geq \int_0^{1}\int_x^{1}\frac  1 {y^{2}} dydx=\int_0^{1}(\frac 1 x-1) dx =\infty$.

Comment: why do you invoque tonelli's theorem ? can you detail a bit more your answer please ?

Comment: You can evaluate the double integral of $|f|$ using iterated integrals. This is becasue $|f|$ is a non-negative  measurable function and  you don't need integrability to write the double integral of $|f|$ using iterated integrals in any order you like. This is exactly what Tonelli's Theorem tells us.  @Dicordi